# Make an object of a class from a string in java

Tags: java, object, javafx

I have different classes, each receives strings and convert it to different html formats. 
Then I have a `chooser` class where i have switch cases to divert the strings e.g. 
i send the strings to `chooser` and `stylename` like this

```
Chooser chooser = new Chooser();
String text = chooser.format(sometext, stylename);
```

the Chooser class is like this:

```
public String format(String sometext, String stylename) {
    switch (stylename) {
        case "NewStyle":
            NewStyle ns = new NewStyle();
            str = ns.refprocess(sometext);
            break;
        case "Anotherstyle":
            Anotherstyle as = new Anotherstyle();
            str = as.refprocess(sometext);
            break;
        case "Tet_Letters":
            Turk_J_Chem tet_letters = new Turk_J_Chem();
            str = tet_letters.refprocess(sometext);
            break;
    }
}
```

it there any short way? so that when i send the `stylename` as `String`, it converts the to `Class`, make its object and then send the `sometext` to that class only?

Comment: pass the fully qualified class name as style text and use Class.forName to load it and use reflection to execute methods

Comment: @Sanjeev why use reflection when adding an interface would solve the same problem much more cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an interface:

```
static interface Style {
    String refprocess(String text);
}
```

and 3 implemntations:

```
static class NewStyle implements Style {
    @Override
    public String refprocess(final String text) {
        return "new style of " + text;
    }
}

static class Anotherstyle implements Style {
    @Override
    public String refprocess(final String text) {
        return "Another style of " + text;
    }
}

static class Turk_J_Chem implements Style {

    @Override
    public String refprocess(final String text) {
        return "Turk_J_Chem's style of " + text;
    }
}
```

Then you can create an enum of classes, and format using the enum:

```
enum Styles1 {
    NEW(NewStyle.class, "NewStyle"),
    ANOTHER(Anotherstyle.class, "Anotherstyle"),
    TET_LETTERS(Turk_J_Chem.class, "Tet_Letters");
    String str;
    Class<? extends Style> clazz;

    Styles1(final Class<? extends Style> clazz, final String str) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.str = str;
    }

}

static String formatUsingEnum1(final String sometext, final String stylename) {
    for (final Styles1 style : Styles1.values()) {
        if (style.str.equals(stylename)) {
            try {
                return style.clazz.newInstance().refprocess(sometext);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException(stylename);
}
```

Or you can populate the enum with real instances:

```
enum Styles2 {
    NEW(new NewStyle(), "NewStyle"),
    ANOTHER(new Anotherstyle(), "Anotherstyle"),
    TET_LETTERS(new Turk_J_Chem(), "Tet_Letters");
    String str;
    Style style;

    Styles2(final Style instance, final String str) {
        style = instance;
        this.str = str;
    }

}

static String formatUsingEnum2(final String sometext, final String stylename) {
    for (final Styles2 style : Styles2.values()) {
        if (style.str.equals(stylename)) {
            try {
                return style.style.refprocess(sometext);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException(stylename);
}
```

But you can insert an abstract function into the enum, with inline implementation for all instances:

```
enum Styles3 {
    NewStyle() {
        @Override
        String refprocess(final String text) {
            return "new style of " + text;
        }
    },
    Anotherstyle {
        @Override
        String refprocess(final String text) {
            return "Another style of " + text;
        }
    },
    TET_LETTERS {
        @Override
        String refprocess(final String text) {
            return "Turk_J_Chem's style of " + text;
        }
    };
    abstract String refprocess(String text);
}

static String formatUsingEnum3(final String sometext, final String stylename) {
    for (final Styles3 style : Styles3.values()) {
        if (style.name().equalsIgnoreCase(stylename)) {
            try {
                return style.refprocess(sometext);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException(stylename);
}
```

Enjoy...

Comment: How is that **shorter**?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: AFAIK, the OP is asking about a *shorter* way

Comment: I have a list of items and a string. I have prepared various classes for each item in the list. When any item is clicked, the string will go to that class to process (each class process the class differently and return different results.